# How to forward traffic to a subnet to a remote server with vpn?

Tags: router, vpn, iptables

Sorry for asking a really generic question, I'm more a developer than a network expert, so please bear with me... :-(

My problem is this: I have
 - server `A`, serving our REST APIs.
 - server `B`, hosting an ipsec strongswan VPN to subnet `C`, that we need to access securely for live data from server `A`, and that we do not control.
I want the traffic to and from subnet `C` on server `A` to be *forwarded*  via server 'B'.

Do you think such a task is feasible?
Should I add a route in the routing table, or should I work with firewall forwarding rules, to start with?

My first attempts have been:

on server A:
    `# ip route add C_SUBNET_IP via B_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP dev eth0`

which did spit on me: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

then, with firewall roules:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s C_SUBNET_IP -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination B_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP
```

which did not allow me to reach any `C` subnet ip:

```
# ping C_SUBNET_IP
PING C_SUBNET_IP (C_SUBNET_IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
...
^C
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9056ms
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you cannot set a gateway on a route that is not in your subnet.
You can solve your issue at server A with the following trick.

First, set the route for your wanted gateway:

```
ip route add B_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP dev eth0
```

Then, set your route:

```
ip route add C_SUBNET_IP via B_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP
```

Now it will work! This is explained in the post below including how to make it permanent in Ubuntu:

https://www.adminsehow.com/2011/09/gateway-on-a-different-subnet-on-linux/

Now that you have reached your server B, you will have to implement some forwarding things there...

Comment: Thanks, Ascanio! :-) The first half of the problem is solved!